# Jquery subtracting 1 from a value with .text and keeping html

Tags: jquery, html, parseint

I'm trying to subtract 1 (one) from a value with jQuery. I've managed to do so like this:

```
$('.notis').text(parseInt($(".notis").text()) - 1);
```

Problem is that the `<a>` this is subtracting from looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="notis"><img src="/images/icons/picture.png">3</a>
```

So the jquery above will subtract 1 (one) from the value, but also remove the image! How can I do this **and** keep the image html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the image in a temporary variable, then add it to the node using the [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method:

```
$('.notis').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);                        // <-- Reference to current elem
    var $img = $this.find('img');               // <-- Reference to <img>
    $this.text(parseInt($this.text(), 10) - 1); // <-- Your logic
    $this.prepend($img);                        // <-- Add image again.
});
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sPnhL/

Additional notes:

- Use `parseInt( ... , 10)` instead of `parseInt( ... )`. Numbers prefixed by a zero will be treated inconsistently across browsers. By specifygin the radix of 10, the number will be parsed correctly.
- `$('.notis')` selects all elements with class `notis`. When you're using `$('notis').text($('notis').text()-1)`, all elements with class `notis` will contain the value **of the first `.notis` element** (because `$('.notis').text()` returns the value of the first `.notis`). That's why I used `.each` in my code.
- When you're going to use `$(this)` more than once, it's worth storing the variable `$(this)` in a temporary variable, for improved efficiency.

Comment: jsfiddle earns you yet another 10 reputation. +1 for the example.

Comment: Thank you!! Great answer, works perfectly and well explained :)

Answer (score 0):

There might very well be a better solution but you can save the children of the link element and re-attach them after you change the text:

```
$('.notis').each(function (index, element) {
    var $children = $(this).children();
    $(this).text(parseInt($(this).text()) - 1).prepend($children);
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/epuxy/ (see the number on the bottom change when you click on the link)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to wrap up the number in a `<span>` and replace its content.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the 3 in a div or span (preferred) class and do it from there.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to put a `span` around your number. This results in the best performance.

**Html**

```
<a href="#" class="notis"><img src="/images/icons/picture.png"><span>3</span></a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.notis > span').text(parseInt($(".notis").text()) - 1);
```

## Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wKqPz/)